# How does useState hook know the calling context in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I am switching from using class components into using functional components in React. I read through their documentation and I like to know how the `useState` hook work.

In their [FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components) they the same question that I'm asking, by saying that each component have a internal list: for storing the state variables, and that the `useState` know the calling component for storing the state variable.

I want to know how does `useState` know the calling component since we don't pass it anything other than the initial state value.

Can someone explain me this with a example? I really want to know how this work.

Comment: @user67 This explains how to use `useState`. I want to how it manages to get access to that internal list

Answer (score 2):

In short, at the begining of render a component, React generate a value like `currentComponentContext`. When you call `useState`, React will bind this state with `currentComponentContext`.

---

see function `mountState` and `dispatchAction` in [ReactFiberHooks.new.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v18.2.0/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js), react bind the state with `currentlyRenderingFiber`.

Answer (score -1):

useState is the state hook provided by react. It returns a “pair” the current state value and a function to update it and also takes a single argument which is the initial value that you want to assign for the state variable.
In the above example count is the state variable and setCount is the function for changing the value and 0 is the default value we are assigning to count. In this example we used a counter as integer value just for demonstration, but we can use any other type like string, object, array etc also we can use multiple state variables defined in a single component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react;
const MyComponent = (props) => {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
return (
    <div>
        <p>Count: {count}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
            Increment Count
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>
            Decrement Count
        </button>
    </div>
)
}
export const MyComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to know how `useState` know the corresponding calling component

Comment: He not ask how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Assuming that seterInClass is an arrow function define to set the value of the variable username.   
 setterInClass = (val) =>{
            this.setState({username:val});
        }
        in a class the initialization is through this.state
        in a functional it is through the userState which acts as a glue.
         this.state = {username:''} + setterInClass is equivalent to const [username, setUsername] = useState('').
        Meaning useState is establishing a relation of setter to the variable username, after initializing it; And avoid us to write this.state to get the value of any variable or having top write const {username} = this.state; 
  So it is cleaner, less code for us and make functionals component looks cute
```

Answer (score -2):

"useState" returns an array with two items. In the first index you have the state itself and in the second index you will get a function to handle that state.
Do this and you will understand :

```
const useStateArray = useState();
console.log(useStateArray[0]);
console.log(useStateArray[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer But this doesn't provide an answer. I asked how `useState` know the corresponding component.

Comment: @Clarke that was your answer.
check this link :
https://medium.com/the-guild/under-the-hood-of-reacts-hooks-system-eb59638c9dba